# Localization of date in mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I localize this one to French please : 
PostDate id DateTime type.

```
@pr.PostDate.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a095fsay.aspx) overload that takes a `IFormatProvider` and pass in a French culture:

```
@pr.PostDate.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy", new CultureInfo("fr-FR"))
```

Though, if you need to do this in multiple locations, it may be easier to set the current culture to a French culture:

```
var frenchCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = frenchCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = frenchCulture;
```